# How to pass data from getStaticProps/getInitialProps to all components with next.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

How can I get data from API in getStaticProps or getInitialProps method and pass this data context to all components in the tree?

For example, I have the following `getStaticProps` for some page:

```
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async () => {
  const { content: locales } = await localizationService.getLocales();

  return {
    props: {
      locales,
    },
  };
};
```

Then I get this data in the page:

```
export const HomePage: FC<IHomePageProps> = ({ locales }) => {
  return (
    <MainLayout>
      <SomeComponent locales={locales} />
    </MainLayout>
  );
};
```

Where SomeComponent - arbitrary deeply nested component, that contains a `<Text />` component inside.
And the `<Text />` component somehow uses this `locales` data

I tried to use react context for that, but it requires default value, which I don't have.

How to avoid many manual passing props `locales={locales}` to each component?

Thanks in advance for any hints :)

Comment: Why can't you use default values? Start with empty values and initialize your context like this. If you want then do not show SomeComponent unless your locales are not empty. AFAIK, context is the way to do this. Don't think of anything else. These other methods only work on page level right now

Comment: I tried this as well. And since the first render on client side happens with context default value, I get hydration error